# TypeScript: return Array as Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

How can I return an array as Observable in getTodoItems()?

It was `Promise<Itodo[]>` and I used `Promise.Resolve(TodoItems)` to return the array.  But when I changed it to use `Observable` instead of `Promise`, I don't know how to return the data and couldn't make it work.

I tried `Observable.of(TodoItems)` but it doesn't know the `.of` function.

I keep getting these errors whatever I tried.  Could you please help me with it?  Thanks.

[image]

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromArray';

import { Itodo } from './todo'

const TodoItems: Itodo[] = [
    { todoId: 11, description: 'Mr. Nice' },
    { todoId: 12, description: 'Narco' },
    { todoId: 13, description: 'Bombasto' }
]

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {


    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    getTodoItems(): Observable<Itodo[]> {

        return TodoItems.map((items => Itodo[]) => <Itodo[]>items);
    }

    addNewTodo(model: Itodo) {        
        TodoItems.push(model);
    }

    getTodoItem(id: number): Observable<Itodo> {
        return this.getTodoItems()
            .map((items: Itodo[]) => items.find(p => p.todoId === id));    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Observable.of` is the correct method you are looking for. On my project, I'm using rxjs5-beta6 and `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';` was enough to use the `of` method. Depending on your project, you may need to explicitly import the `of` method.

If all fails, you may try using `Observable.from(TodoItems)` or even try creating your own observable which return your value.

e.g.

`Observable.create((observer: Subscriber<any>) => {
    observer.next(TodoItems);
    observer.complete();
});`

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

If you need to import it

Answer (score 14):

you should use

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
```

and you can call 'of' directly :

```
of('your data');
```

Comment: `of(['aa','bb'])`